# React render component asynchronously, after data is fetched

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to render a component after data is fetched. If try to load data instantly, component gets rendered but no data is show.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  //typical construct

  getGames = () => {
    fetch(Url, {})
      .then(data => data.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({ links: data });
      })
      .catch(e => console.log(e));
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getGames();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Game gameId={this.state.links[0].id} /> //need to render this part
        after data is received.
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to rerender it actually, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this using short circuit.

```
{
  this.state.links && <Game gameId={this.state.links[0].id} />
}
```

Comment: even though I've tried it earlier, your example does work. thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You could keep an additional piece of state called e.g. `isLoading`, and render `null` until your network request has finished.

**Example**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { links: [], isLoading: true };

  getGames = () => {
    fetch(Url, {})
      .then(data => data.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({ links: data, isLoading: false });
      })
      .catch(e => console.log(e));
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getGames();
  }

  render() {
    const { links, isLoading } = this.state;

    if (isLoading) {
      return null;
    }

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Game gameId={links[0].id} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help! as soon as I reach 15 reputation points I will upvote your answer :). Might be today.

Comment: Would that still be a good option today if data is needed before render, also what if we do not need data state but rather ref instead, how do we trigger re render

Answer (score 0):

Can we use the pattern of "Render-as-you-fetch" to solve the problem.
Using a flag to check whether loading is complete doesn't look like a clean solution..